# add sql field to Now.AddDays function vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have SQL statement with `now.AddDates()` function inside the SQL statement. I need to add value to the `AddDates` function, which is  selected field in SQL.

Here is my SQL statement:

```
 sqL = "SELECT job.id,Fname,LName,jtype,cname,jobDate,jobtime,Status,RemindDate " & _
       "from job left join customer on  job.cusid=customer.id  left join category on " & _
       "job.categoryid=category.id where jobdate between '" & Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & _
       "' and '" & Now.AddDays(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
```

For above `Now.AddDays(3)`, I want to add `Now.AddDays(RemindDate)`.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Dim RemindDate As New Date(2014, 10, 6)     'Connect it to a source.

Dim Sql As String =
    <SQL>
        SELECT
            job.id
            ,Fname
            ,LName
            ,jtype
            ,cname
            ,jobDate
            ,jobtime
            ,Status
            ,RemindDate
        FROM job
        LEFT JOIN customer
            ON job.cusid = customer.id
        LEFT JOIN category
            ON job.categoryid = category.id
        WHERE jobdate BETWEEN '<%= Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>' AND '<%= RemindDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>'
    </SQL>.Value
```